# Storing text files inside root directory

Tags: linux, permissions, root

I am currently in the `/bin` directory. I am trying to create a text file of the content of the
`/bin` directory and direct it to be stored in another file within the `/root` directory. I have entered the command `ls -l >/directoryname/filename` 
yet I don't have permissions to run it. I have tried entering `sudo` before the commmand 
however this doesn't work either. Does anyone know how I can gain permissions 
to store this file? It would be very much appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

When running `sudo ls > /root/out.txt` only the `ls` part of the command is being run with elevated privileges. Because of this the redirection part of your command does not have the permissions needed to access the location you want.

Instead you can use [`tee`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tee) prefixed with `sudo` like so:

`ls | sudo tee /root/out.txt`

Answer (score 3):

An easy solution in order to run a number of commands with sudo is the following:

```
sudo bash -c 'command1;command2'
```

For your situation this would work great:

```
sudo bash -c 'ls -l >/directoryname/filename'
```

This of course is only when you are using bash.

Answer (score -2):

If you enter `sudo chmod 777 /filename` and then run that, you will have permissions to run the commands you previously tried to run. `chmod 777` essentially gives any user read, write and execute permissions in this directory. You can change the permissions later though so users can only read or write for example.

Comment: Changing /root dir to 777 is not great for security.